# Rails Many to Many with Descriptor cield

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have two standard models (Contracts and Agents) with a “standard” many-to-many relationship (ContractAgents).

What I would *like* to do is add an integer field “description” to the ContractAgent table so that I can enum it with (you guessed it) descriptions for that specific relationship (ie “buyers_agent” or “sellers_agent”).

Is this possible?

Here is the code (now that I am on my laptop).

```
//current agent.rb
class Agent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contract_agents
  has_many :contracts, through: :contract_agents
end

//current contract.rb
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :contract_agents
  has_many :agents, through: :contract_agents
end

//current agent_contract.rb
class ContractAgent < ApplicationRecord
end

//current schema for agent_contract
t.integer agent_id
t.integer contract_id
```

Can I make it like the below, or will doing that to the "ContractAgent" model which follows the RoR naming convention mess it up?

```
//proposed agent.rb
class Agent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contract_agents
  has_many :contracts, through: :contract_agents
end

//proposed contract.rb
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :contract_agents
  has_many :agents, through: :contract_agents
end

//proposed agent_contract.rb
class ContractAgent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contract
  belongs_to :agent

  enum description: [:seller_agent, :buyer_agent]
end

//proposed schema for agent_contract
t.integer agent_id
t.integer contract_id
t.integer description
```

Rails 6, Ruby 2.7. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a `has_many :through` association would be best.

One way to do it:

```
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :agents, through: :relationships
end

class Agent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :contracts, through: :relationships
end

# this model will have description, and/or agent_type, etc
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contract
  belongs_to :agent
end
```

In general, `has_many :through` relationships are better than the standard "many-to-many" relationships precisely because of the kind of issue you are running into.

Comment: (first, great username). Thank you and one follow up question - can I just use my existing ContractAgent model (add in the belongs_to as you describe and add the integer to the schema) or will having it in a model follow the ContractAgent naming convention mess it up somehow? I will edit my question to include code

Comment: You can certainly name the model ContractAgent if you wish, but it may provide benefit in the long run if you name it something more descriptive. What are you trying to model between Contract and Agent? It may be useful to call it Deal, for instance.

Comment: So contracts can have multiple agents, and agents can have multiple contracts, thus the many to many, but for each specific relationship the role of the agent may vary (either be a buyer agent or seller agent). If I were modeling multiple factors (say seller/buyer and lead/secondary) than perhaps it would be better to have a ContractAgentDetail model that would but I’m not sure I need that (and could just add those flags to this table just as easily). Any more thoughts? And thank you, again.

Comment: I guess I would recommend to research HABTM vs has_many :through and make whichever decision you think best. There's a lot of info on google, [here's one link](https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many)